# Laravel 4 session won't persist across page loads

Tags: php, session, cookies, laravel-4

I wanted to integrate the [oauth2 server](https://github.com/lucadegasperi/oauth2-server-laravel) into my laravel 4.1 project. The password flow went pretty well but when writing the authorization code flow I encountered some strange problems with the sessions.

The request to generate leads to this function where filtered for logged in users

```
Route::get('security/authorize', array('before' => 'check-authorization-params|auth', function()
{
    [...]
}));
```

Guests are redirected to a form to log in

```
Route::get('security/login', array('before' => 'guest' ,function()
{
    return View::make('users.login');
}));
```

Wich leads to this route where the user should be logged in and redirected to the request he intended to do:

```
public function login()
{
    $creds = array(
        'email' => Input::get('email'),
        'password'=>Input::get('password')
    );

    if(Auth::attempt($creds, true))
    {
        return Redirect::intended('/');
    }

    return Redirect::to('security/login');
}
```

The problem is, despite a positive Auth::attempt() I keep being redirected by the `auth` filter.
I made a few brief tests to check whats wrong by setting and reading session data wich never reached the next request, so i figured out i must have to do with my sessions.

Here's my session config file

```
<?php
return array(
'driver' => 'database',
    'lifetime' => 120,
    'expire_on_close' => false,
    'files' => storage_path().'/sessions',
    'connection' => 'mysql',
    'table' => 'sessions',
    'lottery' => array(2, 100),
'cookie' => 'laravel_session',
'path' => '/',
'domain' => null,
);
```

and here are some things I double checked:

- database connection is correct and sessions show up in my table
- session table fields have the right data types (id - varchar(255), payload - text, last_activity - int(11))
- cookies get set

Comment: This will seem like a bizarre question based on the issue... but are you by any chance using Chrome?

Comment: Redirect::intended('/'); the Redirect::intended() function takes a default parameter to fall back to incase there is no url.intended in session

Comment: I'm on safari, but I tested this on Chrome, Firefox and even IE

Comment: @AyobamiOpeyemi you're right I should set the fallback, but this is not what causes the issues with my session

Comment: Are you being redirected to the '/security/login'?

Comment: after trying to authenticate? no (my login credentials are correct), after trying to reach `security/authorize` yes

Comment: Do check your environment configs.

By default config/local/session.php uses the array driver where as config/session.php is using the file driver

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out, that I did not set up the auth identifier in my user model correctly.
Changing it from this

```
public function getAuthIdentifier()
{
    return $this->email;
}
```

to this

```
public function getAuthIdentifier()
{
    return $this->id;
}
```

fixed everything.